# Explain the * 2 in Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

Tags: javascript

Is this the most efficient way of randomly generating 0 or 1 in javascript?

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

Comment: define efficient. Do you need to generate 1e+6/second?

Comment: @ryan how is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

No, `Math.random() * 2 | 0` and `Math.random() * 2 << 0` seem to be (marginally) [faster](http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-generate-0-or-1/2) in most browsers, which makes sense since it has one less function invocation from the `Math` library.

Comment: Now try to do some real work so that optimiser could not do tricky things: http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-generate-0-or-1-zerkms

Comment: `<< 1` is 1ms faster over 1,000,000 iterations

Comment: I'm finding `Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 1 : 0` to be faster than any of these bitwise methods: http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-generate-0-or-1-zerkms/2

Answer (score 0):

Faster alternatives:

```
(Math.random() * 2) | 0
~~ (Math.random() * 2)
(Math.random() * 2) << 0
```